# Build AOSP for Desire S

Tags: android-source, drivers, cyanogenmod, android

I downloaded AOSP from http://source.android.com & follow the steps of building the system as mentioned. Got system.img and other img files in the building process of the code. Then I fastboot system img to my android htc desire s device. it installed successfully. But when device reboots, it gets stuck in htc logo. I also tried installing imgs in many different ways. nothing worked.

As cyanogenmod & other custom rom designing companies have created custom roms for htc desire, etc, I would like to know how they have solved that issue.
What can be the reason for this. Same code works fine in emulator. I saw that AOSP only works in Google nexus devices. For other devices, in order it to work properly need to have drivers (proprietary binaries). Is that true? If so how can I create my own custom rom by using AOSP? How can I get the proprietary binaries for Desire S or any other device except google's devices?

**Does this AOSP only natively works in Nexsus devices? If so what is the use of it as open source?

Really appreciate any positive reply on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Even for Google phones you need proprietary drivers. Proprietary drivers are needed to work with hardware on a low level. On a higher level you have Hardware Abstraction Layer. Linux kernel of Android works with this HAL and do not work with these proprietary drivers. All other layers of Android (and what you mean under AOSP) work with Linux kernel.

Thus, for every device you need proprietary drivers that are usually should be put into device or vendor directory of AOSP. Just try to find drivers for your phone and find instruction how to build AOSP for your phone.

Comment: hi Yury, your answer was very helpful. As you mentioned, I looked for hardware overlay files for my htc desire & found this https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_bravo. As desire's code name is bravo I think this is a right overlay files released by CyanogenMod. Then I installed custom rom update-cm-7.0.0-Desire-signed.zip from http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=bravo&type=stable & run extract-files script in overlay files. Then it created vendor specific files in AOSP's vendor directory. Then I make the system & fastboot system & boot imgs yet same result. Do u have any idea?